# Efficient way of paging querys PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I've got this really small table I need to run showing some data about registered users(Name, Username).

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY Username ASC") or die(mysql_error());
                        while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                        {
                            echo '<tr><td>' . $user['Username'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $user['FullName'] . '</td>';
                            echo "<td><a href=\"deleteUser.php?id=" . $user['ID'] . "\">Delete</a><br /><a href=\"editUser.php?id=". $user['ID'] . "\">Edit</a></td></tr>";

                        }
```

Anyway, let's say I'll have 50+ users, the all page will be flooded with users.

So I thought of a solution, for every 15 rows pulled up from the database they will have their own "page" (using $_GET).
A friend of mine told me it is something called paging or pagination I don't really remember.  I did find some solutions online but none helped me, some looked so long and I just looked out for another tutorial.

Is there an efficient way of doing this without getting into so much stuff around it?

Comment: Yes, it's called `pagination`.

Comment: So how can I paginate(right way of saying this ?) my querys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called pagination: you can use it in MySQL with the LIMIT statement.

```
$page = (int) $_GET['page'];
$limit = 15;
$offset = $page * $limit;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY Username ASC LIMIT $offset,$limit");
```

Also you need to calculate the total number of pages using the same query without LIMIT:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT count(1) AS total FROM users");
$total = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)['total'];
```

Then you can calculate how many pages you have:

```
$pages = range(0, ceil($total/$limit));
foreach($pages as $p)
    echo '<a href="?page=' . $p . '">' . $p . '</a>';
```

Obviously you should adapt this code to your own needs.

Comment: It's working perfectly, now to make a next and previous buttons I only have to:

       $next = $_GET['page'] + 1;
       echo '<a href="users.php?page='.$next.'">Next</a>'

Comment: Yes, I've also added a more complete example with every page available.